# next(), nextInt(), nextLine(), nextDouble()

Tags: java

Если у нас `int x = scan.nextInt()`, то при вводе *строковых* значений и `double` значений вылазит `Exception`.

Если у нас `String x = scan.nextLine`, то при вводе `int` значений и `double` значений, мы не получаем `Exception` (или можно сказать ошибку), как будто `nextLine()` не для `String` значений, а для всех. Почему, если мы чётко указали:

```
String x = scan.nextLine();
```

Если у нас `double x = scan.nextDouble()`, то при вводе `String` значений он выдаёт `Exception` и `int` (если пишем 123 - то выведет 123.0).

Почему всё отрабатывает как надо, а `nextLine()` принимает любые значения, если мы указали `String`, то есть "задали параметры строго".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что введеные через `nextLine()` числа воспринимаются, как текст - символы цифр, а не числа, с которыми можно производить арифметические действия. Возможно это не очевидно, но цифры тоже могут быть текстом, а так же имеют свои коды в кодовой таблице символов.

Для того, чтобы с полученным таким образом числом можно было производить числовые операции, как сложение или вычитание, его предварительно нужно преобразовать из строки, собственно, в число, к примеру типа `int`. Без преобразования такое число можно только вывести на экран, но не сложить с другим (точнее, мы получим сложение строк, как "123" + "1" будет "1231", а не 124.

В случае `nextInt()` этого, очевидно, не требуется и мы сразу получаем числовой тип (int), для которого доступны любые математические действия. Естественно, этот тип не может принимать символы, кроме чисел и выдает эксепшен

PS: в чем отличие. Рассмотрим пример для таблицы кодов ASCII и числа типа `byte`, так как и тот и другой использует 1 байт для хранения единицы информации.

Символ "1"  имеет код в таблице символов (для ASCII-кодировки это 0x31), но число 1 не имеет кода, оно хранится в виде, собственно, числа в памяти.
Так, к примеру, символы "123" будут хранится, как набор кодов: 0x31,0x32,0x33 и занимать 3 байта (по одному байту на каждый символ-код), в то время, как число 123 будет занимать один байт и храниться в этом байте, как значение - 123. Мы можем сложить его с другим таким же числом (например, 7) и новое число будет по прежнему занимать один байт (будет в этом байте хранится значение - 130). С набором символов-кодов мы этого делать не можем, так как они представлены совершенно другим образом.