# Проверка ввода целого числа и выполнение цикла столько раз. Не работает. char = '2' 50 - что это значит?

Tags: java, char

[image: Дебагер][image: Кусок кода]Помогите пожалуйста, не могу понять почему слово "гав" мне выводится большее количество раз, чем я ввожу. Видимо дело в том, что ch = '2' 50 - из-за чего такое может быть?

Comment: Замените изображения кодом.

Comment: 50 - это ASCII-код символа "2" в десятичной системе счисления. char содержит ASCII-код символа, а не его численное значение в случае если символ это число.

Comment: @pavlofff  да и если не число, то тоже аски код там, разве нет?

Comment: Да, номер символа из таблицы

Comment: @Эникейщик, конечно же для любого символа там ASCII-код. Немного некорректно сформулировал

Comment: здесь немного писал [о разнице между символами и числами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/881149/177345)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Лучше считывать число введенное в консоль методом nextInt().
2. В цикле, в i < ch вы сравниваете i с символом,  который приводится к целому числу, которое соответствует его номеру в таблице символов. В вашем случае i < '2' эквивалентно i < 50, так как 50 номер числа 2 в таблице символов.

Перепишите так:

```
int n;
try {
    n  = scan.nextInt();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Введите целое число");
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    firstDog.voice();
}
```

Comment: А как мне потом сделать проверку, что пользователь ввёл число? Я бы сразу сделал через scan.nextInt(); но не доходит до меня как тогда сделать проверку. Получается, что если пользователь введет "qwe" (например), то программа ложится)

Comment: @Владислав Эстрин, Если ввести qwe вылетит исключение, в блоке try - catch его ловить и обрабатывать.

Comment: Такого я ещё не проходил try - catch :) Может быть ещё какие-то способы подскажете?

Comment: Добавил в ответ

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь